# Gap in invisible boundaries at gate to Cyrodiil in Skyrim Xbox 360

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I looked on the Elder Scrolls wikia on the [White Gold Tower page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/White-Gold_Tower) and it says that there is a gap in the world boundaries at the Pale Pass Gate? Does anyone know where this gap is? I have no DLC/mods.
EDIT:I am referring to the trivia section quote about jumping past the cyrodiil gate.

Comment: What are the down votes for?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to get to the White Gold Tower, or do you want to know about the gap _specifically_ at the Pale Pass gate? There are a bunch of YouTube videos on how to get to the tower, which is why you might have gotten downvotes.

Comment: I an looking for that gap, and i can't watch any videos

Comment: A photo of where the gap is will help alot

Comment: The linked page doesn't mention a "Pale Pass Gate". Are you referring to this quote from the Trivia section: "A complex series of jumps around the gate to Cyrodiil will lead to a gap in the invisible wall at the gate, leading the player into a glitched Cyrodiil. This can also be done to "enter" Morrowind, near Stendarrs Beacon." ?

Comment: Yes. I have seen that gate referred to as the pale pass gate while i was looking for an answer on Google